# Euclid's proof that circles are convex

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, circles

Euclid proves in [III.2](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII2.html) that *circles are convex*: that is, that every point on a chord is inside the circle.

To better understand his proof, I reproved it below, to which I request verification and critique.

**Lemma:** In triangle $\triangle OAB$, with point $P$ on segment $AB$, cevian $OP$ is less than $\max(OA, OB)$.

**Lemma Proof:** Since $\angle OPB$ is an exterior angle to $\triangle OPA$, then $\angle  OPB > \angle A$ since [an exterior angle is greater than an opposite interior angle (I.16)](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI16.html).  Assuming WLOG that $\angle A \geq \angle B$, we have $\angle OPB > \angle A \geq \angle B$ and therefore $OB > OP$ since [in any triangle, the greater side is opposite the greater angle (I.19)](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookI/propI19.html).

**Main Proof:** Consider circle $\bigcirc O$ with center $O$ and chord $AB$.  No point $P$ on segment $AB$ can be external to $\bigcirc O$, since by the lemma, $OP$ is less than the radius of the circle $OA$.

Comment: The link to Euclid you provide has reasons (citations of prior results or definitions) for each statement. Your lemma proof says "Since [stuff] then [statement]". Can you cite a source for that conclusion?

Comment: I think I would put the WLOG assumption first, and then assert $\text{m}\angle OPB > \text{m}\angle OAB$. Otherwise I think it's fine.

Comment: In your lemma statement, do you necessarily want to imply that A and B can be any points in the plane or do you require A and B points on your circle?

Comment: @BrianTung the WLOG is useless in this proof, as OA and OB are both radii.

Comment: @JimN: It's not clear to me that the original poster (didn't want to just use OP here!) is assuming that $A$ and $B$ are both on the circumference in the lemma. I may have commented a little hastily...

Comment: @JimN The lemma is true (and useful) for any triangle in the plane: A cevian must be shorter than at least one side.  Hence, I phrased it that way.

Comment: OK. Then I would write something like: Assume WLOG that $\text{m}\angle OAB \geq \text{m}\angle OBA$. Since $\angle OPB$ is exterior to $\triangle OPA$, $\text{m}\angle OPB > \text{m}\angle OAB$. Therefore, by transitivity, $\text{m}\angle OPB > \text{m}\angle OBA$. Hence, $OB > OP$. The reason is that otherwise, your first sentence sets up a line of reasoning which *requires* $\text{m}\angle OAB \geq \text{m}\angle OBA$; you can't then assume it WLOG. You should assume it first and then employ it. I know it's a nit-pick, but hey, you asked. :-)

Comment: (In other words, suppose you showed $\text{m}\angle OPB > \text{m}\angle OAB$, and then it turned out that $\text{m}\angle OAB < \text{m}\angle OBA$. You would have to backtrack and use the other half of the triangle.)